# Update root view controller after user login + iOS 13 and later

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

Using scene delegate I'm able to set the root view controller.(I'm using Xcode 11.3 and iOS version 13.3 and running my app on iPhone 6+ with iOS 12.4)

What I want is when user login, I need to update the root view controller. For that I did the following

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
static let shared = SceneDelegate()

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

      //some code is here
  }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SceneDelegate {

  func setRootViewControllerBasedOnLogin() {

    if let isLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogin"), isLoggedIn {

        let tabbar = UIStoryboard(name: "Other", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbar") as! UITabBarController

        if var vcs = tabbar.viewControllers {
            vcs.remove(at: 2)
            tabbar.viewControllers = vcs
        }
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabbar

    } else {
       //other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

So when user login in to the app I need to remove a tab item from tab bar and update the root view controller.

So I'm doing as follows.

```
func processLogin() {

  //performing login in this method so when login successful we setting root view controller
  callLoginAPI { response in

    if response.isSuccess {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
       if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
           SceneDelegate.shared.setRootViewControllerBasedOnLogin()
        } else {
          // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm doing this nothing happened. I'm not able to change the root view controller of the app after user successfully login into the app?

Any suggestions? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: add the `window.makeKeyAndVisible()` and check once

Comment: I'm already doing in `setRootViewControllerBasedOnLogin()` method.

Comment: is this possible to attach your project,

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ERrcqJ8-hyWnjTQYryyC8H0eWEyXRQBz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed navigation for both the older version and the new version. So when the user has the latest iOS we need to setup root from `sceneDelegate` and for older version we need to setup root from `appDelegate`

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {

        } else {
            setupRoot()
        }
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {

    }

    func setupRoot() {
        //Setup Your Root Here
        //window?.rootViewController = objNavigationVC
        //window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = window
        appDelegate.setupRoot()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm able to set the root view controller initially. But after user login, I'm trying to update the root view controller but nothing happens.

Comment: @Mahendra - I unable to logout there is no more code for change the RootVC

Comment: Project has just UI only with no functionality. What I am trying to is on some events I want to change root view controller of my application. For now just take an example like when user confirms logout, I want to set login screen as my root view controller.

Comment: I was trying to set the root view controller with different code and nothing worked for me so I may commented or may be deleted that code, I think.

Comment: This answer prevents an app from supporting multiple scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
func presentYourView(from view: YourViwe) {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let mySceneDelegate = view.view.window?.windowScene?.delegate
            if let sceneDelegate = mySceneDelegate as? SceneDelegate {
                sceneDelegate.changeRootViewController(newViewController())
            }
        } else {
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.changeRootViewController(newViewController())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update Swift 5+ , Xcode 13+**

To change `rootViewController` depending upon user has logged in or not, here is the full code for `SceneDelegate`

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        if UserDefaultHelper.isLoggedIn! {
            print("User logged in")
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // this assumes your storyboard is titled "Main.storyboard"
            let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomerMainViewController") as! CustomerMainViewController // inside "YOUR_VC_IDENTIFIER" substitute the Storyboard ID you created in step 2 for the view controller you want to open here. And substitute YourViewController with the name of your view controller, like, for example, ViewController2.
            self.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else {
            print("User Not logged in")
        }
        
    }
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem with PinkeshGjr's answer is that it discardings the window object provided by the scene. Here's what I feel is a better/simpler approach:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    static var current: AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {

        } else {
            window = UIWindow();
            setUpRoot()
        }
        return true
    }

    func setUpRoot() {
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {    
        guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { fatalError() }
        let firstWindow = windowScene.windows.first ?? UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        AppDelegate.current.window = firstWindow
        AppDelegate.current.setUpRoot()
    }
}
```